# XStream and underscores

Tags: java, xml, xstream

It looks like XStream (com.thoughtworks.xstream -> xstream 1.4.2) is handling underscores in element and attribute names in a very strange way. I need to fetch and parse an xml from a customer that are having underscores in their attributes. This is my first try with XStream and I'm a bit disappointed as I was hoping to avoid all the ugly xml parsing.

Here I provide a small test sample to hi light the behaviour. The last example shows my problem.

```
public class MyTest {
  public void testIt() {
    C1 a = new C1();
    a.a_b= "a_b";

    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.processAnnotations(C1.class);

    String xml = xstream.toXML(a);
    Logger.info(xml);

    C1 b = (C1) xstream.fromXML(xml);
    Logger.info(b.a_b);

    C1 c = (C1) xstream.fromXML("<C1 a_b=\"a_b\"/>");
    Logger.info(c.a_b);
  }
}

@XStreamAlias("C1")
class C1 {
@XStreamAsAttribute
String a_b;
}
```

This outputs

```
INFO: <C1 a__b="a_b"/>
INFO: a_b
INFO: null
```

Now my question - is there a way to make XStream understand a single underscore?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XStream uses the underscore to escape characters in identifiers that are valid in Java but invalid in XML (see [here](http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#XML_double_underscores)). So the underscore itself has to be escaped. You can use a custom `NameCoder` as described in the FAQ.

That said I normally can get along with the `NoNameCoder`. But: Don't use underscores in Java property identifiers, if possible; it is untypical for Java and against the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: Thanks very much. XStream(new StaxDriver(new NoNameCoder())) didn't work so I'll investigate making a custom one.

Comment: NoNameCoder does work. I just forgot to add @XStreamAlias("a_b") to the variable when I changed it to ab based on your suggestion about java naming conventions.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me:

```
XStream xs = new XStream(new DomDriver("UTF-8", new XmlFriendlyNameCoder("_-", "_")));
```

Comment: Worked for me. XmlFriendlyReplacer() is depricated.

Comment: Awesome. Worked great.

Comment: Thanks it's really helpful

Answer (score 5):

I used:

```
XmlFriendlyNameCoder nameCoder = new XmlFriendlyNameCoder("ddd", "_");  
XStream xmlStream = new XStream(new Dom4JDriver(nameCoder));
```

and it worked great!
I am using x-stream version 1.4.5.
Hope it helps!

Comment: `XStream xs=new XStream (new Dom4JDriver (new NoNameCoder()));`  works for 1.4.4

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver("UTF_8", new NoNameCoder()));
```

Comment: works on 1.4.7 only with `"UTF8"` instead of `"UTF_8"`

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver("UTF_8", new NoNameCoder()));
```

It worked but it increases the excution time/ parsing time to 4-5minutes